# Definition of complex-valued forms using exterior algebra and tensor products

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products, complex-geometry, exterior-algebra

Let $M$ be a complex manifold. I have seen the bundle of complex valued $k$-forms defined as $\Lambda^k(M) \otimes \mathbb{C}$. What this means is that if $V := T_xM$ for some $x \in M$, then the fiber at $x$ is $\Lambda^k( \hom_\mathbb R (V, \mathbb R) ) \otimes_\mathbb R \mathbb C$.
What I know is that:
$$
\Lambda^k( \hom_\mathbb R (V, \mathbb R) ) \otimes_\mathbb R \mathbb C \simeq_\mathbb R \hom_\mathbb R (\Lambda^k (V), \mathbb C)
$$
and the $\mathbb R$ vector space on the right hand side is isomorphic to the $\mathbb R$-vector space of $\mathbb R$-multilinear alternate maps from $V^k$ to $\mathbb C$.

However, I have also seen that for example $(1,0)$-forms are characterized by being $0$ on $(1,0)$-vectors, and $(1,0)$ vectors live inside $V^\mathbb C:= V \otimes_\mathbb R \mathbb C$. So it must be the case that these complex valued forms take as arguments elements from $V^\mathbb C$.

So the question is, how do I see elements in $\hom_\mathbb R (\Lambda^k(V), \mathbb C)$ as maps taking as arguments elements from $(V^\mathbb C)^k$?

The only two options that I can logically think of to make my forms take arguments from $V^\mathbb C$ are either
$$
\Lambda^k( \hom_\mathbb R (V^\mathbb C, \mathbb R))\otimes_\mathbb R \mathbb C 
\simeq_\mathbb R
\hom_\mathbb R(\Lambda^k(V^\mathbb C), \mathbb C),
$$
i.e. $\mathbb R$-multilinear maps from $(V^\mathbb C)^k$ to $\mathbb C$ (seen as an $\mathbb R$-vector space),
or
$$
\Lambda^k( \hom_\mathbb C(V^\mathbb C, \mathbb C)) 
\simeq_\mathbb C 
\hom_\mathbb C(\Lambda^k(V^\mathbb C), \mathbb C)
$$
i.e. $\mathbb C$-multilinear maps from $(V^\mathbb C)^k$ to $\mathbb C$ (seen as a $\mathbb C$-vector space).

It is not clear to me whether one of these two latter vector spaces is isomorphic with $\hom_\mathbb R(\Lambda^k(V), \mathbb C)$ and if so, over which field - over $\mathbb R$ or over $\mathbb C$. This is why I don't know whether my question is one of convention or of linear algebra.

In short, when we say complex-valued forms, do we mean $\hom_\mathbb C(\Lambda^k(V^\mathbb C), \mathbb C)$ as a $\mathbb C$ vector space? Do we mean $\hom_\mathbb R(\Lambda^k(V), \mathbb C)$ as an $\mathbb R$-vector space or, if not, as a $\mathbb C$-vector space etc.? And are some of these in fact equivalent?

Comment: Let's just consider $\mathbb C$-linear $g : V^{\mathbb C} \to \mathbb C$. Clearly $g$ restricts to an $\mathbb R$-linear map $V \to \mathbb C$; but also any $v \in V^{\mathbb C}$ is of the form $v_R + iv_I$ for $v_R, v_I \in V$, and by linearity $g(v_R + iv_I) = g(v_R) + ig(v_I)$, so it is enough to specify $g$ as $\mathbb R$-linear on $V$ (you can check that scalar multiplication is covered by this too). Thus $\mathbb R$-linear $f : V \to \mathbb C$ extends uniquely to $V^{\mathbb C}$ by defining $f(v_R + iv_I) := f(v_R) + if(v_I)$. Does that help, or did I misunderstand the issue?